# Getting a methods Return type via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, introspection

I am getting the attributes from an incoming object which I will check it's values.

I wish to know if there is a way via reflection that I can obtain not only the value from attribute but also it's type?

would

```
result instanceof Integer.Class
```

work for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the safest and most universal way. It's null-safe, you don't need an extra != null check:

```
SomeClass.class.isInstance(result)
```

**Reference:**

[`Class.isInstance(Object)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `result.getClass()`

Comment: Ok well how would that work when returning from
` Object result = method.invoke(obj, new Object[0]);`
Surely wouldn't that return just the Object Class?

Comment: The .getClass() will return the concrete type, so if you are result is a String, getClass() will return String.class, if result is an Integer, result.getClass() will return Integer.class.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Use [Class.isAssignableFrom()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)